# Salesforce Rest API {"errors":["Message MTIwNToxMTQ6MA is not valid for the client."]}

Tags: java, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities, salesforce-marketing-cloud

Because of the work needs, I want to push the message by calling the salesforce Rest API, refer to the official documentation link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/postMessageListSend.html, but an error was reported during the test. I don't understand what the messageId here is, it is obviously the id of the message.

I checked the official documentation and the message data list on Salesforce, and I don't know what the problem is with messageID. In addition, there is no relevant error message in the Salesforce forum.

This is my code:

```
@Test
  public void pushMessage() {
    String path = "/push/v1/messageList/MTIwNToxMTQ6MA/send";

    ETRestConnection connection = client.getRestConnection();
    String value = "{\n"
        + "    \"inclusionListIds\": [\n"
        + "        \"5de5df40-9e58-ec11-ba2c-d4f5ef424xxx\"\n"
        + "    ]\n"
        + "}";

    Response response = null;
    try {
      response = connection.post(path,value);
      System.out.println(response.getResponsePayload());
      System.out.println(response.getResponseMessage());
      System.out.println(response.getResponseCode());
    } catch (ETSdkException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

The execution result is:

```
{"errors":["Message MTIwNToxMTQ6MA is not valid for the client."]}
Bad Request
400
```

Comment: I dont see that you have an *Authorization Token* defined anywhere in your request...

Comment: The Salesforce Marketing Cloud Java SDK can automatically acquires and refreshes Marketing Cloud access tokens.We just need to generate ETClient according to fuelsdk.properties.

Comment: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Java

Comment: If your authorized is valid and everything is proper, then the messageId you are using does not belong to the client you are using.  Please validate if the API key (messageId) is for the same client you are using.

Comment: As you said, messageID in api (GET /push/v1/message/{messageID}) and messageId in api (POST /push/v1/messageList/{messageId}/send) are not one thing. Personally, I think that messages are sent one by one, so messageId should be used to uniquely identify the message, but if it's not useful, how do I know which message is sent.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, however `messageId string Required The API key of the message definition (configured in the MobilePush user interface)`  MessageId  == API Key

Comment: In the link: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_mp_provisioning_info.htm&type=5, maybe I can get the API key, but as mentioned in the previous reply, I don't understand the meaning.

Comment: For an app, suppose there are many messages, how do I know which message to send

Comment: as you know, I created message according to the following [tutorial](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_mp_outbound_message.htm&type=5)